# HEAD~4^2 meaning

Tags: git, git-log

In a Udacity lesson covering relative commit references, it says:

> ^ indicates the parent commit, ~ indicates the first parent commit
>
> The main difference between the ^ and the ~ is when a commit is
>   created from a merge. A merge commit has two parents. With a merge
>   commit, the ^ reference is used to indicate the first parent of the
>   commit while ^2 indicates the second parent. The first parent is the
>   branch you were on when you ran git merge while the second parent is
>   the branch that was merged in.

According to the lesson, based on the following output of `git log --graph --oneline`, the commit with SHA `f69811c` is `HEAD~4^2` relative to the (topmost, with the head pointer) commit `9ec05ca`.

So HEAD~4 on its own means the first parent, while ^2 means it's also the second parent? Don't these things contradict each other? Any clarification appreciated.

[image: graph]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2221658/1030675

Comment: Instead of reading third-party tutorials, I recommend [the Git docs themselves](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection).  `~n` says chase a first-parent link that many times, default 1, `^n` says chase the nth-parent link, default 1.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`X~n` means: The `n`th ancestor of `X`.

`X^` means: The parent of `X`. This is equivalent to `X~1`.

If `X` has more than one parent, one needs to distinguish between them when using the `^` notation. So `X^1` would be the first parent, `X^2` would be the second parent, and so on. `X^` is equivalent to `X^1` (and also equivalent to `X~1`).

In your example, starting from commit `9ec05ca`, which is `HEAD`:

- `db7e87a` is `HEAD~1` (or alternatively `HEAD^`).
- `796ddb0` is `HEAD~2` (or alternatively `HEAD^^`).
- `1a56a81` is `HEAD~4` (or alternatively `HEAD^^^^`, but nobody would use that).
- `e014d91`, being the **first parent** of `1a56a81`, is `HEAD~5`, or `HEAD~4^`, or `HEAD~4^1`.
- `f69811c`, being the **second parent** of `1a56a81`, is `HEAD~4^2`.

#### Reference

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions

Comment: Thank you, I'm not grasping your last two points. Is Udacity wrong in saying ~ means first parent?

Comment: It's not wrong though a bit confusing. `~n` means "select the nth generation ancestor, always following the first parents", while `^n` means "among the previous generation, select the nth parent."

Comment: Since e6c65a6 is on the branch that was merged into master, is it also a second parent of 1a56a81 (merge commit), in addition to f69811c?

Comment: @NatalieCardot No, `e6c65a6` is not a parent of `1a5681` at all, it is one of its grandparents (because it is the parent of `f69811c`).

Comment: Bonus question: What is the other grandparent of `1a5681`?

Comment: 1a5681's other grandparent is 209752a (plus, its great grandparent is 3772ab1). I think I finally understand :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally wrong, but it's a bit too short: since the "~" operator is performing a depth search (nth ancestor, which actually corresponds to the nth last commit on a single branch), its argument can't specify a parent if they are many of them. It hence assumes it should always follow the first one of them. This correlates with [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50430722/7426932), where we were discussing about parent order.